# Rails 5 POST for Create Action has Empty Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My questions is very similar to [Rails 5 API POST Create params empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305358/rails-5-api-post-create-params-empty) but the answers aren't helping. Params is set but the request payload is being lost.

```
[1] pry(#<Api::RegistrationsController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[2] pry(#<Api::RegistrationsController>)> params.require(:data)
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: data
```

**Request Headers**

```
Host: test.lvh.me:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1038
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://test.lvh.me:4200
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Referer: http://test.lvh.me:4200/register/individual-academics
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Raw Payload**

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"first-name":"Test","last-name":"User","email":"lkjlkj@kjhjk.com"}}}
```

**Update**
If I set up the same app using Rails 4, this works perfectly with no changes in the payload, so it looks like it's something with the way Rails 5 handles requests, potentially?

**Update 2**
`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.string)` correctly parses into a hash, but is not included in the params. I can certainly do params.merge! but this feels like a bad call.

request.format is: `#<Mime::Type:0x007f89b6c63df0 @hash=2978300210816280263, @string="application/json", @symbol=:json, @synonyms=["text/x-json", "application/jsonrequest"]>`

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. Stack Overflow is not a forum; you can put the answer in a self-answer. In fact, you already did so. Nothing is added by putting it into the question too

Answer (score 4):

In order to fix this, you need to add the following line to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.api+json", :json
```

Comment: I don't get why I had to add this especially that while booting rails app it logs that some JSON definition was already there.  However it solved my issue after moving to fast_jsonapi Thx @Michael

Comment: Would like to know WHY this works - it's not immediately obvious from elsewhere on the interweb. I've seen mentions of this being used _in conjunction with_ respond_to in the controller but latter seems not to be needed.